# How to import google cloud speech recognition in Google App Engine (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python, google-speech-api

I want to use google.cloud library on my Google App Engine python application. In my local all my tests work since I installed this library on my local. I was expecting it to be supported in GAE by default but it's [not supported](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27).

This the error I got:

```
from google.cloud import speech
ImportError: No module named cloud
```

I had a look at adding 3rd party libraries at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

After following the instructions I got another error.

```
(/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:263)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~goooogle-translate/20180126t023051.407206565499030997/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    from google.cloud import speech
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~goooogle-translate/20180126t023051.407206565499030997/lib/google/cloud/speech/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from google.cloud.speech.client import Client
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~goooogle-translate/20180126t023051.407206565499030997/lib/google/cloud/speech/client.py", line 25, in <module>
    from google.cloud.speech._gax import GAPICSpeechAPI
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~goooogle-translate/20180126t023051.407206565499030997/lib/google/cloud/speech/_gax.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.gapic.speech.v1.speech_client import SpeechClient
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~goooogle-translate/20180126t023051.407206565499030997/lib/google/cloud/gapic/speech/v1/speech_client.py", line 31, in <module>
    from google.gapic.longrunning import operations_client
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~goooogle-translate/20180126t023051.407206565499030997/lib/google/gapic/longrunning/operations_client.py", line 45, in <module>
    from google.gax import api_callable
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~goooogle-translate/20180126t023051.407206565499030997/lib/google/gax/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import multiprocessing as mp
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.util import SUBDEBUG, SUBWARNING
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 41, in <module>
    from subprocess import _args_from_interpreter_flags
ImportError: cannot import name _args_from_interpreter_flags
```

I hardly understand this one. If you have done this before please let me know how to setup google.cloud inside GAE.

Comment: try: sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech

Comment: @BenyaminJafari I tried that and tried to deploy again but there where no changes on source code: Uploading 0 files to Google Cloud Storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already answered in this other Stack Overflow post about [using Client Libraries in App Engine Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143283/how-to-combine-google-app-engine-with-cloud-natural-language/48150126#48150126), GAE Standard does not support Google Client Libraries, so you can either go with **App Engine Flexible**, a **Compute Engine instance** or work with the **REST API** (which also has a Python library that works in App Engine Standard).

If you specifically need to use the `google.cloud` library, you will have to use App Engine Flexible and not Standard, but in case you would rather work with the Standard environment, below I share the code for a sample App Engine Standard application using Cloud Speech API through the [Google API Python Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started). This library is not built-in for GAE Standard, so you will have to [vendor it as if it was a third-party library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library). To do so, you will have to create the `lib` folder in your local application's directory, and the `requirements.txt` file I share below, and then install this library with the command `pip install -t lib/ -r requirements.txt`.

Files needed to run this sample GAE Application:

***requirements.txt***

```
google-api-python-client
```

***appengine_config.py***

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

***app.yaml***

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: True

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

***main.py***

```
import webapp2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    # Presentation page
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('This is a sample App Engine Standard application working with Cloud Speech API! :)\n\nGo to /speechAPI to transcribe your audio file (you will need to upload it to one of your Cloud Storage buckets)!')

class Recognize(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    # Working with Python API Client Library (NOT NEW CLIENT LIBRARIES)
    def get(self):
        # Add credentials
        credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
        service = build('speech', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

        # Methods available in: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/speech/v1/python/latest/index.html
        collection = service.speech()

        # Build the data structure JSON-like
        data = {}
        data['audio'] = {}
        data['audio']['uri'] = 'gs://<BUCKET>/<FOLDER>/<FILE>'
        data['config'] = {}
        data['config']['encoding'] = '<ENCODING>'
        data['config']['languageCode'] = '<LANGUAGE_CODE>'
        data['config']['sampleRateHertz'] = <SAMPLE_RATE>

        # Build the request and execute it
        request = collection.recognize(body=data)
        res = request.execute()

        # Webapp2 Response
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write(res)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/speechAPI', Recognize),
], debug=True)
```

This application also works in the Local Development Server, so you can test it with the command `dev_appserver.py app.yaml` before deploying it to App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech`

Or:

I'm using another library,
Does this method help you up?

```
import speech_recognition as sp
import time

print("Say something!")

while True:
    rec = sp.Recognizer()
    with sp.Microphone() as mic:
        audio = rec.listen(mic)
    try:
        print(rec.recognize_google(audio))
    except sp.UnknownValueError:
        print("I cannot understand what you said")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("Say again")
    except sp.RequestError as e:
        print("Error".format(e))
    word = rec.recognize_google(audio)

    if word == 'goodbye':
        break
```

**Installation:**

```
sudo pip install SpeechRecognition

sudo pip install pyaudio
```

If you found an error:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio

sudo apt-get install libjack-jackd2-dev portaudio19-dev
```

Then again:

```
sudo pip install pyaudio
```

If you found error try this:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pyaudio
```