# from google.cloud import speech_v1 ---- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I use Cloud Shell Console to write python code that uses Google Speech to Text

Steps taken:

1. Google cloud shell console to write the code
2. `gcloud app deploy`
3. Error message:
   `File "/home/vmagent/app/main.py", line 3, in <module> from google.cloud import speech_v1 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'`
4. `pip list` run on the console shows that 'google' is included

Comment: Do the answers here help you?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459712/how-to-import-google-cloud-speech-recognition-in-google-app-engine-python

Comment: Did you try to reinstall the client library? Are you trying to deploy it in App Engine Standard or Flexible? Also could you provide your configuration files and a code snippet to check on it?

Comment: I am using standard flex on gcloud. And I  deploying using browser base console interface.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide the requirements.txt , app.yaml and a sample of the code ?

Comment: What is in your `requirements.txt` file? It should contain the [`google-cloud-speach`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-speech/) package.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pip3` instead of `pip`.

It took me hours to find out the files had been in another directory all along.